# Special Offer 4+1 or 7+2

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, discount, promotions, cart-rule

I am wanting to run a special offer on a group of products where if they buy 4 they get a 5th free, **OR** if they buy 7 they get two additional free i.e. 4+1 (total of 5+ in basket) **OR** 7+2 (total of 9+ in the basket).
I have two issues - I can not work out how to run a 7+2, also I would need the 7+2 to superseed the 4+1, i.e the customer doesn't get the 4+1 and the 7+2

Thanks

These are the current settings...

[image: actions]
[image: conditions]

[image: 9+1]

[image: 8+2]

[image: 5+5]

Answer (score 2):

Would this not work for you? Maybe you have to tweak around a bit with the exact rules but it should somehow work then.

[image: Would that work?]

Comment: Thank you Thomas, that looks like it would work a treat. What would you suggest using in the Actions to get this to work?

Comment: Did you try the one i mentioned in the image?

Comment: Yes I set the conditions, thank you :-) I just wasn't sure what to set in the actions to make it work - at the moment its set to Buy X get Y free as this worked for the 4+1, but i wasn't sure if it would work with a 7+2?

Comment: No it currently isn't working

Comment: Can you explain the issue more then. 4+1 works but 7+2 won´t work?

Comment: No at the moment it isn't discounting at all. I can't work out how to insert images here to screenshot what the settings currently are...

Comment: update your original question for that

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible with these two rules

### 4+1

**Condition:** If total quantity  less than  7  for a subselection of items in cart matching ALL  of these conditions: (your product selection)

**Action:** buy 4, get 1 free, If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE: (your product selection)

### 7+2

**Condition:** If total quantity  equals or greater than 7  for a subselection of items in cart matching ALL  of these conditions: (your product selection)

**Action:** buy 7, get 2 free, If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE: (your product selection)

You should probably assign a maximum discount amount to the 7+2 rule additionally, unless you also want "buy 14, get 4 free".

Also, this solution does not work, if you want "buy 12, get 3 free" additionally (i.e. to choose the best fitting combination for each qty).

Comment: thankyou, this has worked great for the 4+1 rule - it stops it applying if greater than 5 in the basket. However, I can not get the 7+2 rule to work - I have edited original post to show the actions and conditions. Many Thanks

Comment: Buy "X" should be `7`, not `9`.

Comment: That has worked great now thankyou, but only if the quantity is all of one item, i.e 9 of one item rather than 5 of one and 4 of another?

Comment: Or if there is 8 of one item and one of another item it just discounts one qty

Comment: I've added images above to show

Comment: Then try it with "Buy X, get the cheapest free", which you used originally IIRC. It's not a core feature but seems to do what you need.

Comment: we tried that but could not get it to discount more than 100%